# InfoPath setting conditional default value in radio buttons

Tags: infopath, default-value

I have created an infopath form which is connected to SharePoint Library. I would like to set a default value automatically for the radio buttons which are available in that form when one checkbox is cleared.

**For instance;**

- Do you need help? **Checkbox**

**Radio Button Options:**
A
B
C

If the checkbox above is not clicked, then set A as a default value automatically.

Do you know how I can do that without inserting any codes, in other words with using rules and/or conditional formatting options in InfoPath.

Your urgent support is so much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to change conditionally within an InfoPath form, you will **need** to use either rules or code. How else should InfoPath know what to do? So, set the default values, then when the checkbox field is changed, run a rule to change the radio button value.

Comment: indeed @teylyn, i need to use rules and I am OK with using them. However, I am not sure about what you suggested; Let me elaborate my question. I have bunch of checkboxes in an infopath form. And I would like to set values for radio buttons that are available in the form ( different from checkboxes ) automatically based on the fact that whether the checkboxes are clicked or not. Basically what I want Infopath to do is the following: If Checkbox X is cleared by the user, then set ''No'' automatically in radio buttons which is other section of the form. Clarification is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, set a rule on the Checkbox X field that fires when the field changes. Let the rule test if Checkbox X is false, and if it is, set the value of the radio button choice field to the desired value. That's how it works for me. If it does not work for you, please post more info about your setup and maybe a sample file with dummy data.

Comment: Thank you very much @teylyn, that was very helpful. Let me put it easier way for those who seeks for an answer for this issue: Rather than trying to add rule to your radio button, try to add rule to your checkboxes. Basically you need to add two rules to your checkbox; one for the checkbox is clicked and one for the checkbox is cleared. If you would like set your radio buttons not selected for a specific condition you should add a rule which sets that field empty. Thanks again...

Comment: That's what I wrote above: Set a rule on the checkbox. I never said anything about setting a rule on the radio buttons.